# Project not connecting to real time database - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem with real time database not working, I copied a project from GitHub and made a new project in firebase with my app ID, added the JSON file to my app and changed the `write` and `read` rules to `true` but still not working or showing anything in the terminal

source code :

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class CustomData extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomData({this.app});
  final FirebaseApp app;
  @override
  _CustomDataState createState() => _CustomDataState();
}

class _CustomDataState extends State<CustomData> {
  final refrenceDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final MovieController  = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ref = refrenceDatabase.reference();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Real Time DataBase'),backgroundColor: Colors.red,),
      backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          Center(child:
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Movie title',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                TextField(controller: MovireController, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: (){
                  ref.child('Movies').push().child('movie title').set(MovieController).asStream();
                }, child: Text('Submit'))
              ],
            ),

          ),)
        ],),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,  // 2021-3-23
    ".write": true,  // 2021-3-23
  }
}
```

Comment: And do you get any error?

Comment: Please share your database rules, check if you have put the `google-services.json` file properly and well, has it been connected to Firebase Analytics or any other firebase service properly? Are you receiving any error?

Comment: No, it shows nothing, nor that it's connecting nor any errors @Renaud Tarnec

Comment: I am not receiving any errors or any thing in the prompt and analytics show nothing too, I made sure to add `google-services.json` in the proper place under `app`, I also added the database rules. @Preet Shah

Comment: Also, how exactly do you know it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So, from what I have seen, you do not receive any errors. So, it means that your firebase is connecting properly.
The second thing is the following error in the code. I don't know what you expect to do with the following code but it is not correct.

```dart
// Firstly, you're passing a TextEditingController instead of a string.
// Secondly, you're streaming data but you're not accessing it anywhere.
ref.child('Movies').push().child('movie title').set(MovieController).asStream();
```

```dart
ref.child('Movies').push().set({
  "movie title": MovieController.text,
});
```

This should push data to your Database.

Comment: I was getting an error `error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (extra_positional_arguments at [realtime_test] lib\Customdatabase.dart:42)` `so I added .set()` `ref.child('Movies').push().set({
  "movie title": MovieController.text,
});` but still nothing is showing up in the database @Preet Shah

Comment: Well, you're right. I have updated my answer accordingly. However, the error should be some error log or something.

Comment: indeed there was something wrong with the database, I created a new project and set the location to US instead of EU and now it works perfectly @Preet Shah